# Mask Jquery erro ao digitar uma letra

Tags: jquery, jquery-masked-input

Estou com o seguinte problema estou usando por exemplo o código de mask

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('.cpf').mask('999.999.999-99');
 });
```

perfeito ele funciona e aceita só números, porém se eu aperar qualquer letra ele põe no input o ..- que são os caracteres da mascara, e não queria que nada fosse adicionado quando aperto qualquer letra.

Comment: Você quer que apareça apenas os números?

Comment: isso, na verdade se eu digitar só os números a mascara funciona perfeitamente, mas se eu digitar por exemplo a letra A no input aparece o ..-   que seria a mascara sem os numeros

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É só verificar se a tecla pressionada é um número. Você pode usar a função `isNaN()` em um evento `keydown` para retornar `false` caso a tecla não seja numérica. Além disso, criei uma array com os códigos de algumas teclas de controle para que as mesmas não caiam no `if`, ou seja, para que elas funcionem no campo, já que não são numéricas, mas são úteis para controlar o cursor e seleção caso necessário:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

   var teclas = [
      8,    // backspace
      16,   // shift
      17,   // ctrl
      35,   // end
      36,   // home
      37,   // ←
      39,   // →
      46,   // delete
      13    // enter
   ];


   $('.cpf').mask('999.999.999-99').on("keydown", function(e){
      
      var key = e.key; // pega o valor da tecla
      var keycode = e.keyCode || e.which; // pega o código da tecla

      if(isNaN(key) && !~teclas.indexOf(keycode)) return false;

   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.12/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

<input class="cpf">
```

Resumindo, se a tecla pressionada não tiver um valor numérico e seu código não estiver na array, não irá surtir efeito no campo.

Comment: ficou perfeitoooooooooooooooo muito obrigado

Comment: blz... só fiz uma correção: a array `teclas` fora do evento.

Comment: agradeço mesmo amigo